# SB Admin 2 sidebar not displayed active class background color for new item added and dashboard is always active by default

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkZj3.png)
if I added a new item as Projects and clicked then it's not active with the different background color. By default always Dashboard is active.

I have successfully integrated the SB Admin2 theme into my ASP.Net C# projects. Only the active background color is not working. Please help me as I am new to this.

```
 <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="Projects.aspx">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-mobile-alt"></i>
                    <span>Projects</span></a>
            </li>
```